# Не заходит в блок each

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Здравствуйте! Задача состоит в том, чтобы добавить посты после клика на кнопку при помощи ajax. Файл обработчик работает исправно (как мне кажется)

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['start'])) {

    include('infofordb.php');

    $start = $_POST['start'];

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

    $query ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.", 5";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

    $articles = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $articles[] = $row;
    }

    echo $articles;
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

ajax вроде как тоже работает, но не работает цикл each - я использую его для добавления постов

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var start = 5;

                $('#load').click(function() {

                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'handler.php',

                        type: 'POST',

                        //dataType: 'json',

                        data: {start : start},

                        success: function(data) {

                            $.each(data, function(index, item){

                                alert(data[index].path);

                                $('main').append(
                                                '<article class="news"><div class="picture"><img src="/image/' + data[item].path +
                                                + '"></div><div class="aboutpost"><h2 class="aboutpost-title">' + data[item].title + 
                                                + '</h2><p class="aboutpost-description">' + data[item].description + 
                                                + '</p></div></article>');

                            });
                        },

                        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                            var msg = '';
                                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                                } else {
                                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                                }
                            alert(msg);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Таблица news состоит из 4 столбцов - id, path, title, description (в обработчике все верно выводится).

Также, если добавить тип возвращаемых данных (json), то выдается ошибка "Requested JSON parse failed." С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: с тем что маловероятно что `echo $articles` выдаст вам json. я бы сказал что вероятность этого равна нулю.

Comment: а еще можно передать `{ start: " 1 union select * from news #"}` к примеру

Comment: @teran дело в том, что если я укажу тип возвращаемых данных, а в обработчике json_encode, то isset в обработчике не пройдет. Если уберу тип возвращаемых данных, то заработает, то есть ко мне вернется json. Его нужно раскодировать как я понимаю при помощи `var res = JSON.parse(data)` - но эта строка не заработает.

Comment: вам нужно сделать `echo json_encode($articles)`, а не просто `echo $articles`,  как у вас написано.  У вас там счас приходит строка `Array` вместо ожидаемых данных. Можете проверить, открыв в браузере инструменты и вкладку сеть.  jquery на входе сама определит, что речь про json.

Comment: @teran json появляется, но не присоединяет блоки к main. Почему так?

Comment: потому что, вероятно, вам нужен `#main` или `.main`, а не просто `main`

Comment: @teran спасибо большое за помощь! Оказывается дело не в main, а том что я присоединял